# Forward local port or socket file to remote socket file

Tags: mysql, ssh, port-forwarding, socket, socat

Quick question - I run two linux boxes, one my own desktop and the other my VPS. For security reasons on the VPS end I opted for socket connections to MySQL (`/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock`). I know I can tunnel like this: `ssh -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 user@site.com` if I set up the remote sql server to listen on some port, but what I want to know is can I do something like: `ssh -L /path/to/myremotesqlserver.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock` thereby tunnelling two sockets, as opposed to two ports?

A perfectly acceptable solution would also be to forward a local port to the remote socket file, but where possible I'm trying not to have tcp servers running on the remote box.

(and yes, I know tcp would be easier).

Comment: If the reason you don't want to use TCP on the mySQL box is because of security concerns (i.e. remote attacks, etc) you can ofcourse either firewall it, and if that is not good enough, make mySQL only listen to 127.0.0.1 for its TCP connections, then you can tunnel through SSH easily. If not, I support the socat solution below.

Comment: http://lwn.net/Articles/609321/ OpenSSH 6.7 will bring socket forwarding

Comment: @Hubbitus is this feature available now, if so, can you provide an example answer?

Comment: That comment was in answer form, but converted into comment by someone. And I see now you already suggest answer below.

Answer (score 60):

Altough in the time, when the question was asked, it was really impossible,
but it is possible nowadays.

You can to both: `UNIX` => `TCP` and `UNIX` => `UNIX` forwarding.

For example `(LOCAL PORT TO REMOTE)`:

```
ssh \
  -R /var/run/mysql.sock:/var/run/mysql.sock \
  -R 127.0.0.1:3306:/var/run/mysql.sock \
  somehost
```

For example `(REMOTE PORT TO LOCAL)`:

```
ssh \
  -L /var/run/mysql.sock:/var/run/mysql.sock \
  -L 127.0.0.1:3306:/var/run/mysql.sock \
  somehost
```

Notice the `-R` and `-L`

It is possible since OpenSSH 6.7.

Comment: I managed to forward my local socket to remote server socket using above and run docker client remotely (it could be done by ssh directly, but where is the fun in that :) `ssh -L /home/user/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock dockerhost -N`

Comment: The answer has -R but for sockets it's -L

Comment: @malhal The difference between `-L` and `-R` is not about TCP versus sockets but the direction of the forwarding. Both options supports TCP ports as well as sockets.

Comment: It looks like it is impossible again (Since OpenSSH 8.0, RHEL8) https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1527565

Answer (score 41):

## Forward a local socket on demand

- Setup SSH public key authentication
- Install `socat` at both ends
- create a directory locally for your sockets, inaccessible to other users.

```sh
export SOCKET_DIR=~/.remote-sockets
mkdir -p $SOCKET_DIR
socat "UNIX-LISTEN:$SOCKET_DIR/mysqld.sock,reuseaddr,fork" \
EXEC:'ssh user@server socat STDIO UNIX-CONNECT\:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

then

```
mysql -S $SOCKET_DIR/mysqld.sock -u mysqluser -p
```

stolen from [forwarding unix domain sockets with ssh and socat](http://www.debian-administration.org/users/dkg/weblog/68)

Comment: This is awesome and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

i haven't done this, but i would try with [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/).  maybe something like:

```
ssh xxx@yyy.zzz -L 9999:localhost:9999 "socat TCP-LISTEN:localhost:9999 UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock"
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/path/to/local/socket TCP:localhost:9999
```

again, i have never done anything like this.

Comment: I'll give it a go and let you know how it goes. I've been using the tcp-based implementation.

Comment: I can't get it to work at the moment but +1 anyway for the idea, I like it. I'll let you know if I fix it.

Comment: +1 looks like a useful utility.

Answer (score 9):

No more socat is needed since ssh 6.7. You can forward unix domain sockets directly like:

```
ssh -nNT -L $(pwd)/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock user@someremote
```

More info: https://medium.com/@dperny/forwarding-the-docker-socket-over-ssh-e6567cfab160

Comment: I also found this useful for connecting to a local socket as a different user. This let me run client programs against a server process which disconnects certain user IDs (connections coming from its own job runners).

Comment: Forwarding a socket to the same machine, but different directory controlled by a different user, using sshd to authenticate the access? What is your usecase?

Comment: Directory permissions/access aren't a problem. Rather, [a particular daemon](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-nix-daemon) drops any connection attempts made by users in a certain group (supposedly to prevent newbies getting confused). Using ssh allows those users to connect (via the tunnelled socket) as if they were a user not in that group, and hence not get disconnected.

Comment: Interesting, funny how you mean the nix-daemon, I'm also dealing with issues regarding that. I'm wondering why nix-daemon is dropping connections to users in a certain group? Is this a security configuration thing? Or related to: https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#idm140737318362784?

Comment: According to [the commit message](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/commit/88b5d0c8e89afefbc547b6243c5aa5a3ec8176e9) it's to prevent "accidental" usage. I brought it up [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/13#issuecomment-404553374)

Answer (score 2):

Another modification of @mpontes'/@javier's answer that

```
ssh user@remoteserver -L 9999:localhost:9999 'socat TCP-LISTEN:9999,fork,bind=localhost UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock& pid=$!; trap "kill $pid" 0; while echo -ne " \b"; do sleep 5; done'
```

*Cleaner*

```
ssh user@remoteserver -L 9999:localhost:9999 '
  socat TCP-LISTEN:9999,fork,bind=localhost UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock&
  pid=$!
  trap "kill $pid" 0
  while echo -ne " \b"; do
    sleep 5
  done
'
```

#### PROS

1. Works on openssh earlier than 6.7 (like CentOS 7)
2. Kills socat on ssh termination instead of having to re-ssh into the remote server
3. Allows non-public ssh login (unlike ijk solution)

#### Feature

1. Since the `-f` option is not used, you can either use a public key and run in the background via `&` or you could log in interactively and use Ctrl+Z and use the same `$!` to store the pid.

#### CONS

1. Can't easily use the `-f` ssh option, as you'll lose the pid of ssh that way. This method relies on running in the foreground and Ctrl+C to kill.
2. Far more complicated

### Explanation

- `socat ...&` - run socat in background on remote server
- `pid=$!` - store the pid
- `trap kill\ $pid 0` - run `kill $pid` on bash termination
- `while :; sleep...` - sit in an infinite loop
- `echo -ne \ \b` - Echo space followed by backspace. This fails as soon as the ssh is disconnected. With a `sleep 5`, this means that `socat` can run up to 5 seconds after ssh

*Note:* Actually tested using docker, port `2375`, `/var/run/docker.sock`, and environment variable `DOCKER_HOST='tcp://localhost:2375'`, but should work for mysql all the same

### Update

Using [SSH Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1821968/4166604), you can use the `-f` flag using my way, just add the following flags

```
-f -o ControlPath=~/.ssh/%C -o ControlMaster=auto
```

And you'll get

```
ssh -f -o ControlPath=~/.ssh/%C -o ControlMaster=auto user@remoteserver -L 9999:localhost:9999 'set -m; socat TCP-LISTEN:9999,fork,bind=localhost UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock& pid=$!; trap "kill $pid" 0; while echo -ne " \b"; do sleep 5; done'
```

Now you can terminate all the controlled sessions using

```
ssh -o ControlPath=~/.ssh/%C -O exit remoteserver
```

The `-o` options can be saved in your `.ssh/config` file, or you can use -S instead (but you'll still need `-o ControlMaster`)

Comment: I'm using scripts inside a Docker container to deploy code to other hosts.  Your connection logic is amazing but ends when the bash session ends.  This prevents my from calling `docker run ... connect.sh` to setup the tunnel followed by `docker run ... deploy.sh`.  I tried `nohup`, `&`, and `disown` but they seem to break `socat` by closing `stdout` and triggering the `kill`.  Any ideas for tweaks to support this case (i.e. still close when SSH does but survive a disown)?

Comment: OK. This actually works fine (w/ `-f` and `& disown`) in a terminal.  Apparently the issue is created by the script "wrapper".  I'd welcome input but am looking at more appropriate Q&As now.

Comment: @claytond Not sure exactly what you are doing, but yes, all other commands are terminated when pid 1 of a container ends.What I would typically do in your deploy script scenario is use the command "deploy" and write an entrypoint for my container image that will say "if $1 (the command) == deploay then" run the ssh commands, and the deploy commands, and then end, which will close the ssh connection.

You can also `docker run ... connect.sh`, and `docker exec {container name/id} deploy.sh`, so they play together.

Comment: You're right.  I'm actually using `exec` on an already `run` container and the SSH pipe wasn't persisting after `exec` ended.  I clarified that it was due to a quirk with the way scripts are executed.  If I moved the call to it's own script and called `nohup <script.sh> & disown`, it survives the completion of the `exec`.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Javier's answer, this works for me:

`ssh -f xxx@yyy.zzz -L 9999:localhost:9999 "socat TCP-LISTEN:9999,fork,bind=localhost UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock"`

You need `fork` in order to be able to connect multiple times without socat dying once you close the first connection. Also, the way socat lets you specify an address to bind to is through the `bind` option, not as an address before the port.

After this, just connect to `localhost:9999` normally as you would. Then to teardown the tunnel:

`ssh -f xxx@yyy.zzz "killall socat"`

(or something similar, you can do more elaborate things that involve keeping socat's PID)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can using socat.

First do the TCP tunnel with SSH. Then use socat like this:

socat unix-listen:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock,fork,unlink-early tcp:127.0.0.1:3306

Then give permissions to new created socket (chmod 777 may be)

Comment: This is possible since OpenSSH 6.6.

Comment: `chmod 777`: nonononono! Never ever run `chmod 777`. It is practically never required! Not even for "testing purposes". If the file is readable, then it's readable. If it's writable by the `user` or `group` that need to write to it, then it's writable. There is absolutely zero need to give everyone write permissions, and forgetting to `chmod` it back to something sane is exactly how multinationals get hacked. Just don't do it. Ever. I wrote [an introduction of Unix permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35895436/660921). Please read it!